# How can i transfer a value with AJAX.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I would like to send a value to a php-script (servo.php). The php-script should then write the received value in a file (in my case /dev/servoblaster).

The script part of the HTML-file (index.html):

```
<script>
function tiltt() { var tilt = document.getElementById("tiltRange").value;
                   document.getElementById("tilt_Range").innerHTML = tilt; 
                   var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
                   xhttp.open("GET", "servo.php?dir=45", true); xhttp.send();}
</script>
```

The body-part of the HTML-file (index.html):

```
<body>
    <button onclick="tilt()">Tilt</button>

    <input type="range" id="tiltRange" value="0" max="50" min="-50">

    <text id="tilt_Range"></text>
</body>
```

**My Question:** How could i send the value of the slider (the tiltRange-value)? Instead of "45".

You can find the HTML-file and the PHP-file here:

HTML: [Pastebin HTML](http://pastebin.com/XjLBmQdT)
PHP:  [Pastebin PHP](http://pastebin.com/pSUXSnBA)

My final goal will be to send the tiltRange-value and to write it to /dev/servoblaster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can amend your code above to simply append the range value in your AJAX URL...

```
xhttp.open("GET", "servo.php?dir=" + tilt, true);
```